# Is there a general purpose way to test for the existence of a GIL?

Tags: python, cpython, gil

I'm writing a multi-threaded Python application, which will behave differently on systems, depending on the details of the GIL implementation.

Is there a general purpose way for me to test whether the intepreter I'm running on has a CPython style GIL?

Answer (score 1):

No, the stdlib has no API or flag to test for the GIL. For now you can safely assume that all versions of CPython and PyPy have a GIL while IronPython and Jython don't have a GIL.

Python 3.3 and newer have `sys.implementation.name`. In older versions you can use `platform.python_implementation()`.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.implementation.name
'cpython'
>>> import platform
>>> platform.python_implementation()
'CPython'
```